# Receiving SQL Error [28]: (conn=72) error in DBeaver when trying to Load data infile command

Tags: mysql, import, dbeaver

I am new to this, so kindly help me rectify my mistake here.
I am trying to upload a csv file from my local DB into a table in my QA instance using Dbeaver and receiving the following error.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Dirty_Node.csv' 
INTO TABLE dirty_node
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

> Error: SQL Error [28]: (conn=72) LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE asked for file 'C:Dirty_Node.csv' that doesn't correspond to initial query LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Dirty_Node.csv'

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibuilities

First use `/` instead of `\`

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Dirty_Node.csv' 
INTO TABLE dirty_node
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

OR ewsacpe the backslash with a second

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Dirty_Node.csv' 
INTO TABLE dirty_node
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Comment: thanks a lot @nbk :-) Your answer did the trick... I tried locally using MYSQL workbench before using the QA env where I used C:\Dirty_Node.csv to load data, So I didn't even think this would be the mistake I made. Cheers